# PHP query stop after count reached

Tags: php, count

I can't seem to figure this out from the php manual. The following code is giving me the 2nd post that is returned. What I would like to do is get 2 posts and then stop.

```
$count=0;
    $related = p2p_type($connected_type)->get_related( get_queried_object_id() );

            // Display related posts
            if ( $related->have_posts() ) :
            $count++;
            while ( $related->have_posts() ) : $related->the_post();            
        if ($count == 2) {

        echo the_title();   

        } else {

        echo 'this post won't show up'; 
        }

    endwhile; 

                // Prevent weirdness
            wp_reset_postdata();

            endif;
```

Comment: I read your question 5 or 6 times and I can't figure out what you are asking.

Comment: @desimusxvii i think he wants to terminate the loop when count is not equal to 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use  `if($count >2)  break;`     or `break;` in the `else`

break ends execution of the current  while .

for more information check this link [php manual break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)